# PIG Selecting from one Bag with data from another Bag

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm new to HADOOP and PIG.

I have 2 bags:

```
DUMP A:
(1)
(2)
(4)

DUMP B:
(1,John,USA)
(2,Richard,UK)
(3,Ian,Ireland)
(4,Simon,Canada)
```

Bag B has every person listed. Bag A has the ones I am interested in. I am sure that there is a simple way to get just the people I'm interested:

```
(1,John,USA)
(2,Richard,UK)
(4,Simon,Canada)
```

Can someone put me out of my misery?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to join and display the two sets via commands similar to this:

```
JOINSET = join A by $0, B by $0;
DUMP JOINSET;
```

To make this a bit easier to understand, I'd associate names with your 'columns' when you LOAD the datasets initially. You could also filter via the foreach/generate command. So something like

```
INTEREST = foreach A generate $0 as interestID;
RECORDS = foreach B generate $0 as recordID, $1 as name, $2 as location;
JOINSET = join INTEREST by interestID, RECORDS by recordID;
```

Would allow you to join via 'column names' rather than column indexes.